# arrange sql statement according to meta value not working

Tags: mysql, wordpress

i'm pulling my hair out here:

I have a sql statement that is part of an ajax call:

```
SELECT $wpdb->commentmeta.meta_value, $wpdb->comments.comment_ID, $wpdb->comments.comment_date, $wpdb->comments.user_id, $wpdb->comments.comment_content, $wpdb->comments.comment_author 
FROM $wpdb->commentmeta 
JOIN $wpdb->comments ON $wpdb->comments.comment_ID = $wpdb->commentmeta.comment_id 
WHERE $wpdb->commentmeta.meta_key = '_commentsvote' 
AND $wpdb->comments.comment_date >='" . $current_year . "-" . $current_month . "-01' 
AND $wpdb->comments.comment_date <='" . $current_year . "-" . $current_month . "-31' 
ORDER BY $wpdb->commentmeta.meta_value DESC
```

the statement works great, and returns results, however, the order is off. now, i know this is because the meta_value is actually a varchar, and not an int. so, the internets told me to do either a convert or cast:

```
Convert: 
SELECT $wpdb->commentmeta.meta_value, $wpdb->comments.comment_ID, $wpdb->comments.comment_date, $wpdb->comments.user_id, $wpdb->comments.comment_content, $wpdb->comments.comment_author 
FROM $wpdb->commentmeta 
JOIN $wpdb->comments ON $wpdb->comments.comment_ID = $wpdb->commentmeta.comment_id 
WHERE $wpdb->commentmeta.meta_key = '_commentsvote' 
AND $wpdb->comments.comment_date >='" . $current_year . "-" . $current_month . "-01' 
AND $wpdb->comments.comment_date <='" . $current_year . "-" . $current_month . "-31' 
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, $wpdb->commentmeta.meta_value) DESC

CAST
SELECT $wpdb->commentmeta.meta_value, $wpdb->comments.comment_ID, $wpdb->comments.comment_date, $wpdb->comments.user_id, $wpdb->comments.comment_content, $wpdb->comments.comment_author 
FROM $wpdb->commentmeta 
JOIN $wpdb->comments ON $wpdb->comments.comment_ID = $wpdb->commentmeta.comment_id 
WHERE $wpdb->commentmeta.meta_key = '_commentsvote' 
AND $wpdb->comments.comment_date >='" . $current_year . "-" . $current_month . "-01' 
AND $wpdb->comments.comment_date <='" . $current_year . "-" . $current_month . "-31' 
ORDER BY CAST($wpdb->commentmeta.meta_value AS INT) DESC
```

I keep getting sql errors on both of these when i run it as a sql statement (obviously, i convert the $wpdp to just say wp_) out of wordpress. the error is non specific - i.e. "you have an error near as int" for example.

so, two questions, first one is wp specific, and the second is a sql:

1. i'm pretty sure there's a way to write all this as an arg array i can pass into wp_query, but i'm unsure of how to do a join. code examples here would be super helpful.
2. why why WHY is this sql statement unwilling to convert that last colomn to an int?

Thanks Wp and SQL geniuses for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short version is that you can't `CONVERT` to `INT` - the proper type would be `SIGNED`. Read more about [`CAST` and `CONVERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert). That said there are some other changes that you should make to make the code more readable and more secure.

First, if you use table aliases you cut down on the need to reference `$wpdb` so many times and it can make even more complex queries more readable (if you are joining to a meta table more than once on different keys for example).

More importantly you should use `$wpdb->prepare()` to escape your SQL - inserting variables into the statement is asking for a SQL injection. It probably also makes sense to leverage `BETWEEN` and `DATE_ADD` for your `WHERE` clause - not all months have 31 days. If you do want to pass in the start and end date, you should still use `%s` as a placeholder in the SQL and use `prepare()` to populate it.

```
global $wdbp;

$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT votes.meta_value, c.comment_ID, c.comment_date, c.user_id, c.comment_content, c.comment_author
    FROM {$wpdb->comments} c
    JOIN {$wpdb->commentmeta} votes 
        ON votes.comment_id = c.comment_ID AND votes.meta_key = '_commentsvote'
    WHERE
        c.comment_date BETWEEN %s AND DATE_ADD(%s, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    ORDER BY CONVERT(votes.meta_value, SIGNED)
SQL;

$date = "{$current_year}-{$current_month}-01";
$query = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $date, $date );
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
```

Comment: This totally worked beautiful, with the exception of: instead of using $results = $wpdb->query( $query ); i had to use $results = $wpdb->get_results( $query ); - the query one didn't return any results. thank you for the super clean code example and the prepare suggestion :)

Comment: Fixed the example to show `get_results` instead of `query`, sorry about that.